# tkinter python script does not work windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I am studying Python. Doing exercises from a book.
I wrote a simple example script using Tkinter module.
I use Windows XP Pro.

This is it: ( literally from the book )

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

This is supposed to open a blank window on the desktop.
When I run this, either from command line or inside Idle,
the script exits within one second, and no window appears.

I tried importing other modules, and they all work fine.
What am I missing?

Comment: I note that the post doesn't break the lines between commands..But I did make a break...don't know yet how to display code as <pre>

Comment: Don't you get any diagnostic output when you run this from the console, at least if you use `python.exe` and not `pythonw.exe`?

Comment: Are you saying that when you literally type "python script.py" in a windows command prompt and press the return key, that the prompt returns with absolutely no errors or warnings or output of any kind, and no tkinter window shows up?

Comment: What version of python do you have installed. The code in your question will only work for python 2.x. For python 3.x you need to use lowercase `tkinter` on the import statement.

Comment: @PhilD'Agostino: Btw I edited your post to get the code formatted correctly.

Comment: What's your traceback? Do you get an `ImportError` or something else?

Comment: Thanks to all who replied:

Comment: Sam B: No diagnostic output at all. I used python,exe to run it.                   Bryan O: same answer..using your method...also I use python 2.7.9    Zizouz: No traceback. I have gotten traceback errors before, but that was because I misspelled a word.             Nope, when I run this script, I see that something is happening - but in a few seconds the command prompt returns, and no window appears...I tried putting Tkinter.py in the same directory with my script...same result...stumped..   I downloaded wxPython, tried that - it works..but of course all my lessone are using Tkinter!

Comment: Update: I installed Python 2.7.9 on a different PC ( acer Laptop ) and retried the Tkinter script. Same result! A real puzzler.

Answer (score 0):

Ok folks, I finally discovered the bug...why Tkinter would not work..
The script creates a window frame on screen, but as soon as the script
ends, the frame disappears..not predicted by the book...I found this out by
putting a call to raw_input as the last line..but then pressing  would
not get the script to exit...had to use Control-C 
weird..maybe it's a glitch in Windows?

I downloaded a wrapper for Tkinter called Graphics.py...this has an explicit
win.close method - and until you call it, the frame remains..

So I guess I'll use  that...

If anyone has some other workaround, I'd appreciate hearing it..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Following code works perfectly under PyCharm 2017.2.4 on Win 8.1 Python 3.6:

```
from tkinter import *

def hello(e):
    print("Hello")


tk = Tk()
# btn = Button(tk, text = "click me", width = 30, height = 5)
# btn.bind("<Button-1>", hello)
# btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```